# Using .change() on a dropdown box

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have a dropdown box that I am setting another event to.  This is how I have my HTML set up:

```
      <p> Please select a number:
<select name="selectNumber" id="selectNumber">
  <option value="1" <%if (number.equals("1")) {%>selected<%}%>>1</option>
  <option value="2" <%if (number.equals("2")) {%>selected<%}%>>2</option>
  <option value="3" <%if (number.equals("3")) {%>selected<%}%>>3</option>
  <option value="4" <%if (number.equals("4")) {%>selected<%}%>>4</option>
  <option value="5" <%if (number.equals("5")) {%>selected<%}%>>5</option>
  <option value="6" <%if (number.equals("6")) {%>selected<%}%>>6</option>
</select>
</p>
<div id="orgDiv">
   <p> HELLO!! </p>
</div>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#orgDiv').hide()
    });
    $('#selectNumber').change(function(){
      $('#orgDiv').show();
    });
```

So it obviously hides the div when the DOM is finished loading.  The problem I am having is as soon as I click the dropdown box......it shows the div.  It does not wait until I select something in the dropdown.  Is there another event I can use?

Comment: just throw an if statement in that checks to make sure the `.val()` of the drop-down isn't the default value before you show `#orgDiv`

Comment: Do you have any click handler for this select dropdown?

Comment: @Shankar I dont know if I understand your question. I could try .click(), but I believe it would do the same thing

Comment: What browser are you using? I tested this in IE and mine does not change when I click the dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen for the change event inside document ready.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#orgDiv').hide()
      $('#selectNumber').change(function(){
        $('#orgDiv').show();
      });
    });
```